# Отображение изображение на экран PyQt5 доступных в bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, sqlite

как вывести изображение на экран PyQt5 если изображение храниться в бд в `bytes`

```
import sys,sqlite3
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication,QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor, QFont,QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt,QSize
class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
        connect = conn.execute("SELECT Data from Images")
        for row in connect:

            self.label_im_qrcode = QLabel()
            import io, qrcode
            b = io.BytesIO(row[0])
            img.save(b, 'png')
            data = b.getvalue()

            pixmap = QPixmap()
            pixmap.loadFromData(data)


            self.label_im_qrcode.setPixmap(pixmap)
         self.setGeometry(300, 300, 280, 170)
         self.setWindowTitle('Draw text')
         self.show()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    con = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
    cur = con.cursor()
    fin = open('woman.jpg', "rb")
    img = fin.read()
    binary = sqlite3.Binary(img)
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Images(Data) VALUES (?)", (binary,))
    con.commit()
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Воспользоваться нужными методами: [QImage.loadFromData](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#loadFromData-1) или [QImage::fromData](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#fromData-1).

Для `QPixmap` есть метод [QPixmap.loadFromData](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#loadFromData-1)

[Пример](https://github.com/gil9red/qrcode_gui/blob/18c55c73d41fd3e04605b3654ea503c6ef4c2fc1/mainwindow.py#L82) из [qrcode_gui](https://github.com/gil9red/qrcode_gui/tree/master):

```
import io

text = self.input_text.toPlainText()
img = qrcode.make(text)

b = io.BytesIO()
img.save(b, 'png')
data = b.getvalue()

pixmap = QPixmap()
pixmap.loadFromData(data)

self.label_im_qrcode.setPixmap(pixmap)
```

---

[Больше](https://github.com/search?l=Python&q=user%3Agil9red%20loadFromData&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) моих [примеров](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=user%3Agil9red%20fromData&type=Code)

---

**После обновления вопроса:**

Показываю [пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/b63f23bd2199ebe29681794e7b3b831ade44aaae/sqlite3_example/append_image/main.py) добавления в базу данных `SQLite` картинки и отображения ее на виджете Qt:

```
import sys
import sqlite3
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


if __name__ == '__main__':
    con = sqlite3.connect('test.sqlite')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Images (
        Data BLOB
    )
    ''')
    con.commit()

    with open('capture.png', mode='rb') as f:
        binary = sqlite3.Binary(f.read())

        cur.execute("INSERT INTO Images(Data) VALUES (?)", (binary,))
        con.commit()

    app = QApplication([])

    w = QWidget()
    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    w.setLayout(layout)

    for (img_data,) in con.execute("SELECT Data from Images"):
        pixmap = QPixmap()
        pixmap.loadFromData(img_data)

        label = QLabel()
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)

        layout.addWidget(label)

    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: обновил вопрос вот на примере данного кода как туда ваш код вставить, не совсем понятна работа данного кода. Я так понимаю в переменную `text` пользователь вводит qrcode а потом он из модуля `qrcode` обрабатывается или `qrcode` это как бд

Comment: @Дмитрий, `qrcode` создает картинку, которая хранится в объекте `Pillow`, тот объект поддерживает сохранение в файловый объект, вот я и подсунул BytesIO, а после из него вытащил байтовый массив (bytes) и поместил в loadFromData, чтобы получить картинку объекта `Qt`. Надо было раньше ваш код приводить в вопрос. Кст, какое описание таблицы Image?

Comment: Все равно не понимаю если данные уже в `bytes` как их выводить на экран по вашему приложению я понимаю так что картинка хранится в каталоге с приложении ну или что то подобное. Попытался подставить в свой код у меня почему то не выводится то изображение ( обновил код ). скорее всего не правильно делаю с             
`b = io.BytesIO()`

Comment: Сейчас покажу пример

Comment: Благодарю понял