# Не все данные записываются при сохранениии изображений в pymysql: Corrupt JPEG data

Tags: mysql, python, sql, python-3.x, pymysql

Как корректно поместить изображение в MySql через pymysql. Пробовал как в [предыдущем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/742690/255866), но там использовал `sqlite3` сейчас же при попытке сделать так же:

```
import sys
import pymysql
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
con = pymysql.connect(
        host=host,
        port=3306,
        user=user,
        password=password,
        db="test",
        charset='utf8mb4')
cur = con.cursor()
with open('woman.jpg', "rb") as f:
    img_data = f.read()
    binary = pymysql.Binary(img_data)
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Images(Data) VALUES (%s)", (binary,))
    con.commit()
app = QApplication([])
w = QWidget()
layout = QVBoxLayout()
w.setLayout(layout)
cur.execute("SELECT Data FROM Images")
d = cur.fetchall()
for (img_data,) in d:
    pixmap = QPixmap()
    pixmap.loadFromData(img_data)
    label = QLabel()
    label.setPixmap(pixmap)
    layout.addWidget(label)
w.show()
```

получается ошибка:

> Corrupt JPEG data: 1 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9
>   JPEG datastream contains no image

а в саму базу записывается как я понимаю не полностью весь бинарный код
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может конечно проблема в самой структуре таблице я не совсем уверен что должна быть `bynary` потому что в `sqlite` была `numery`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно было поменять в `MySQL` тип данных `binary` на `blob`
 ,так как `binary` имеет ограничение на кол-во символов в нем и равно 255 как в `char` 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После чего заново закинуть в бд картинку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]